# Compile-time configuration of installation directories

Tags: rust, packaging, configure, autotools, autoconf

The [autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html) are providing a suite of utilities allowing the developer to configure the source code during compilation specifically to ease packaging.

One of the capabilities is the definition of several [installation directory variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Standard-Directory-Variables.html) set during compilation and which avoids making assumptions on where the application is to be installed.

For example:

| Variable | Default |
| --- | --- |
| `prefix` | `/usr/local` |
| `datarootdir` | `${prefix}/share` |
| `sysconfdir` | `${prefix}/etc` |
| `localstatedir` | `${prefix}/var` |
| ... |  |

How to mimic this behavior in Rust at compile time? Is there any existing standard or best practices for such need?

I'd like to make use of system paths but without having them fully hard-coded and allowing the packager to customize part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`std::env`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) or [`std::option_env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html) macros to get an environment variable at compile time. This can be used to set install variables as environment variables when building your program.

If you want to additionally set defaults conveniently, here's a macro:

```rust
/// Get an environment variable during compile time, else return a default
macro_rules! env_or {
    ($name:expr, $default:expr) => {
        // This is needed because `Option.unwrap_or` is not a const fn:
        // https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91930
        if let Some(value) = option_env!($name) {
            value
        } else {
            $default
        }
    };
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```rust
const PREFIX: &str = env_or!("PREFIX", "/usr/local");
```

To concatenate `PREFIX` and `/share`, you can use the [`concatcp`](https://docs.rs/const_format/latest/const_format/macro.concatcp.html) macro from the [const_format](https://crates.io/crates/const_format) crate as follows:

```rust
const DATAROOTDIR: &str = const_format::concatcp!(PREFIX, "/share");
```